# Bot is not starting and gives no error messages

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a currency system but I'm not able to get the bot started.

**The problem** with this is that I don't even get an error message or anything like that.

I already tried renaming the `Client` to `bot` and `message` to `msg`, but unfortunately that didn't help either.

This is my current code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client();
const { Users, CurrencyShop } = require('./dbObjects');
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
const currency = new Discord.Collection();
const PREFIX = '!';

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'add', {
    /* eslint-disable-next-line func-name-matching */
    value: async function add(id, amount) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        if (user) {
            user.balance += Number(amount);
            return user.save();
        }
        const newUser = await Users.create({ user_id: id, balance: amount });
        currency.set(id, newUser);
        return newUser;
    },
});

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'getBalance', {
    /* eslint-disable-next-line func-name-matching */
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        return user ? user.balance : 0;
    },
});

bot.once('ready', async () => {
    const storedBalances = await Users.findAll();
    storedBalances.forEach(b => currency.set(b.user_id, b));
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

bot.on('message', async msg => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
    currency.add(msg.author.id, 1);

    if (!msg.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    const input = msg.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim();
    if (!input.length) return;
    const [, command, commandArgs] = input.match(/(\w+)\s*([\s\S]*)/);

    if (command === 'balance') {
        const target = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
        const balanceembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`${target.tag} has ${currency.getBalance(target.id)} **Pogcoins**`);

        return msg.channel.send(balanceembed);

    } else if (command === 'inventory') {
        const target = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
        const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: target.id } });
        const items = await user.getItems();
        const itemsembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`${target.tag} currently has ${items.map(i => `${i.amount} ${i.item.name}`).join(', ')}`)
        if (!items.length) return msg.channel.send(`${target.tag} has nothing! LOL NOT POG VERY NOOB`);
        return msg.channel.send(itemsembed);
    } else if (command === 'transfer') {
        const currentAmount = currency.getBalance(msg.author.id);
        const transferAmount = commandArgs.split(/ +/g).find(arg => !/<@!?\d+>/g.test(arg));
        const transferTarget = msg.mentions.users.first();

        if (!transferAmount || isNaN(transferAmount)) return msg.channel.send(`Sorry ${msg.author}, I didn't understand. Maybe you speaking trentish XD`);
        if (transferAmount > currentAmount) return msg.channel.send(`Sorry ${msg.author}, you only have ${currentAmount}. U poor UOUOUOUOUOUOUOUO`);
        if (transferAmount <= 0) return msg.channel.send(`Yea yea sure, ${msg.author}, you want to rob noob? Here we don't rob, understand? Geez`);

        currency.add(msg.author.id, -transferAmount);
        currency.add(transferTarget.id, transferAmount);

        const giveembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`Successfully transferred ${transferAmount} **Pogcoins** to ${transferTarget.tag}. Your current balance is ${currency.getBalance(message.author.id)} **Pogcoins**`)

        return msg.channel.send(giveembed);
    } else if (command === 'buy') {
        const item = await CurrencyShop.findOne({ where: { name: { [Op.like]: commandArgs } } });
        if (!item) return msg.channel.send(`That item doesn't exist. **You live in an imaginary world noob**`);
        if (item.cost > currency.getBalance(msg.author.id)) {
            return msg.channel.send(`You currently have ${currency.getBalance(msg.author.id)}, but the ${item.name} costs ${item.cost}! You still poor bruh...`);
        }

        const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: msg.author.id } });
        currency.add(msg.author.id, -item.cost);
        await user.addItem(item);

        const buyembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`You've bought: ${item.name}. Use = completly useless, but it's good to have something lol`)

        msg.channel.send(buyembed);
    } else if (command === 'shop') {
        const items = await CurrencyShop.findAll();
        return msg.channel.send(items.map(item => `${item.name}: ${item.cost} **Pogcoins**`).join('\n'), { code: true });
    } else if (command === 'leaderboard') {
        return msg.channel.send(
            currency.sort((a, b) => b.balance - a.balance)
                .filter(user => client.users.cache.has(user.user_id))
                .first(10)
                .map((user, position) => `(${position + 1}) ${(client.users.cache.get(user.user_id).tag)}: ${user.balance} **Pogcoins**`)
                .join('\n'),
            { code: true },
        );
    }
});

bot.login('my token');
```

Comment: So when you try to run the bot it really doesn't say anything in your debugging console?

Comment: nope, there's nothing

Comment: Try applying `process.on('uncaughtException', function (exception { console.log(exception); });` to your code. This should write errors to your console

Comment: Didn't work boi

Comment: Is your bot hosted or running on local?

Comment: Running on local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231031/discussion-between-toasty-and-danikexx).

Comment: Got it fixed by yourself? @Danikexx